# Entity Framework (EF) OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, out-of-memory

I have > 67000 records coming to my system from another source.  After applying business rules to those records I have to store them to the database.  I use following code for doing that:

```
        using (var context = new MyEntities())
        {
            var importDataInfo = context.ImportDataInfoes.First(x => x.ID == importId);

            importedRecords.ForEach(importDataInfo.ValuationEventFulls.Add);

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

After executing code I am getting following error (OutOfMemoryException)

```
    Error in executing code|Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.*   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.KeyManager.<WalkGraph>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.KeyManager.GetPrincipalValue(PropagatorResult result)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.GenerateValueExpression(EdmProperty property, PropagatorResult value)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildSetClauses(DbExpressionBinding target, PropagatorResult row, PropagatorResult originalRow, TableChangeProcessor processor, Boolean insertMode, Dictionary`2& outputIdentifiers, DbExpression& returning, Boolean& rowMustBeTouched)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCompiler.BuildInsertCommand(PropagatorResult newRow, TableChangeProcessor processor)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.<ProduceDynamicCommands>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__71`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
```

I am using EF 4.0.

My question is there is limitation on number of records to save?  What is the best practice to save big number of records (save them in chunks? what about transactions?).

Thanks everybody in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably want to send that data down in batches of probably 1024 records at a time.

You could wrap the loop that batches the records in a transaction so you could rollback the entire sequence if desired. Do note that this transaction will most likely escalate to a distributed transaction.

Distributed transactions can only be applied against a server that has the Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS-DTC) service running. There is a notable performance penalty when working distributed transactions.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  - Yes I changed my code to test if it works with chunks of records and indeed it works, but my question is I have not read anything about limiting number of records on SaveChanges() in EF.  Have you heard from MS about this restriction?

Comment: @Vlad Bezden the restriction isn't connected specifically to EF, it's just part of working with .NET technology. When you ETL 67K records you likely have 200k+ objects in memory. You have the 67k original records, you have the 67k EF objects, and each most likely instantiates a number of state tracking entities inside the context for each object so that right there is already 67k+67k+67k, I wouldn't be surprised that a couple other ancillary objects get created along the way too. EF works on a deferred query pattern it doesn't do real work until you call SaveChanges that's why the OOM occurs.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Not clear how the fragment should be changed. It would be nice to see as an update to the original question. I do have existing code where there is .Add inside foreach loop and SaveChanges immediately after loop. Not clear if include SaveChanges in a loop, does it always clear what was added via .Add

Comment: @MicMit you want to batch changes to the server. So for X records, lets say 1024, you want to call SaveChanges, every 1024 records. If you use a for loop you could easily write `if(i%1024 == 0) context.SaveChanges()` Then you'd still have 1 final call to savechanges outside the loop as you'll likely not have a perfect last sized batch. When working with large record sets you might also want to look into the `yield return` operator and work with enumerables to not load entire record sets into memory.

Comment: @Chris It didn't make any difference for some reason for batch of 10. Do you know any references to code samples for the approach you had suggested . Did you actually mean overriding/rewriting savechanges or additions also.

Comment: @MicMit nothing about overriding savechanges, just to call it with less data being prepared. If you're getting an OOM for 10 objects, something seems seriously wrong.

Comment: @Chris Understandably something went wrong. I meant actually your mentioning  yield and enumerables - it was unrelated to EF , wasn't it ?

Comment: @MicMit ah about yield return, i don't have any posts off hand but if you google yeild return that should turn up lots of information, also you might want to look into Rhino ETL made by Ayende. Rhino ETL is entirely based on using enumerables to avoid loading more data than needed into memory.

Answer (score 4):

In general, .NET is limited to addressing 2GB of memory in a single collection or other object. This is because even in a 64-bit environment, indexers use 32-bit integers (with a max value of 2 billion and change). Even for simple data types like integers, the size of a single int means that only 500 million ints can be stored in a single array. For larger value types like structures, the maximum number of elements of a collection gets really small.

If you're in a 32-bit environment like Windows XP, there are even lower limits; the maximum memory space for the ENTIRE PROGRAM cannot be greater than 2GB. This places some pretty high restrictions on an ETL like yours, and I would not be surprised at all that your program is running out of memory trying to process 67k in-memory records at once.

The solution is to handle records in smaller batches if you can. Try constructing a statement based on the ID, where you return the top 100 records where the ID (hopefully auto-generated) is greater than the largest ID you've already retrieved. Once a record is processed, dispose of it (or just orphan it and let the GC do its job).

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I am getting OOME when I am calling SaveChanges method.  I don't have any issue on .NET code with my application, I tested processing import records with > 1,000,000 and system is fine, it is only fails when I am calling SaveChanges on EF

Comment: Probably because ORMs like EF have to determine what changed so they can make an efficient UPDATE statement. That requires pulling the record again, and storing the changes in some collection it will use to generate the update. Also, the strings that form the update commands are collections of characters, and multiply 67,000 by a up to a couple thousand characters per UPDATE and you can easily reach the length limits of a string. Again, try setting a "batch size" for incoming and outgoing records, which will limit the amount of incoming data AND the size of the commands going out.

Comment: Sorry for late entry: Is it the SaveChanges() call that causes the OOME - so if I call SaveChanges more often then I can minimise the risk of this?  I have a foreach loop, but I was processing ALL items before saving, whereas there is nothing to stop me saving each item individually.